# Interpolation issue in bash shell script

Tags: bash, sh, interpolation, wget

My current code is

```
#! /bin/sh
yday=$(/usr/bin/date  --date="yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
outfile='/var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/'${yday}'.csv'
infile="https://example.com/export/vendors?lower_date=${yday}&higher_date=${yday}"
echo $outfile
echo $infile
```

The output is

```
.csvr/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/2022-01-06
```

```
&higher_date=2022-01-06com/export/vendors?lower_date=2022-01-06
```

Also tried as

```
outfile=$("/var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/$yday.csv")
```

and

```
outfile=$('/var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/'${yday}'.csv')
```

These generate

> .csv: not found.example.com/seb/fetch_csv.sh: 3: /var/www/apidev.example.com/seb/fetch_csv.sh: /var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/2022-01-06

The intended use of the variables is in `/usr/bin/wget -q -O $outfile $infile`

How do I get the intended path and url correctly interpolated into my variables?

Comment: Not sure that your question is, the `echo $outfile` shows the desired string: `/var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/2022-01-06.csv`?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not bash. A script you run with `sh` is a POSIX sh script, not a bash script: Even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, it runs in compatibility mode with some features turned off when started under that name. (Think of sh-vs-bash like C-vs-C++; two different languages, one being a superset of the other, and some implementations of one supporting features borrowed from the other, but very distinct nonetheless).

Comment: Also, `echo $varname` is not a safe and effective way to check a variable's contents. If your shell is bash (`sh` doesn't support any of these features), you can use `declare -p varname`, or `printf 'varname=%q\n' "$varname"`, or for new enough versions of bash, `printf '%s\n' "varname=${varname@Q}"`. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566), and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: ...any of the approaches suggested above would show the `$'\r'`s -- aka carriage returns -- in your data, which are what are sending the cursor back to the front of the line when printed.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the lines of your script does not end in CRLF.  Run `dos2unix` against it.  The mixed output is likely caused by it.

Also you need to quote your variables properly, and uniformly if possible:

```
yday=$(/usr/bin/date --date=yesterday '+%Y-%m-%d')
outfile="/var/www/api.example.com/seb/imports/${yday}.csv"
infile="https://example.com/export/vendors?lower_date=${yday}&higher_date=${yday}"
echo "$outfile"
echo "$infile"
```

Comment: In vi I am not seeing the ^M which sometimes indicates Windows carriage returns but i did write in Win IDE so rewrote from scratch in vi on Debian box and that did fix it so I presume you are correct.  Thanks!